# Spring boot some tests fails with @Transactional, but it run well without they

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, testing

I'm using spring boot 3 and junit 5. I implemented this tests for check agency CRUD operations.

```java
@SpringBootTest
class AgencyTest {

    @Autowired
    AgencyCreate agencyCreate;

    @Autowired
    AgencyUpdate agencyUpdate;

    @Autowired
    AgencyFind agencyFind;

    @Autowired
    AgencyDelete agencyDelete;

    @Transactional
    Long createAgency(){
        AgencyCreateDto agencyCreateDto = AgencyCreateDtoMother.random();
        return agencyCreate.create(agencyCreateDto).getResult().get("id");
    }

    @Test
    @Transactional
    void create_agency(){

        Long agencyId = createAgency();
        assertTrue(agencyId >= 100000L);
    }

    @Test
    @Transactional
    void create_agency_with_invalid_parameters(){

        AgencyCreateDto agencyCreateDto = AgencyCreateDto.builder()
                .name(null)
                .build();

        assertThrows(Exception.class, () -> agencyCreate.create(agencyCreateDto).getResult().get("id"));
    }

    @Test
    @Transactional
    void update_agency(){

        Long agencyId = createAgency();

        AgencyUpdateDto agencyUpdateDto = AgencyUpdateDtoMother.random();
        assertDoesNotThrow(() -> agencyUpdate.update(agencyId, agencyUpdateDto));
    }

    @Test
    @Transactional
    void update_agency_that_not_exist(){

        AgencyUpdateDto agencyUpdateDto = AgencyUpdateDtoMother.random();
        assertThrows(Exception.class, () -> agencyUpdate.update(ContentGenerator.customId(), agencyUpdateDto));
    }

    @Test
    @Transactional
    void find_agency_by_id(){

        Long agencyId = createAgency();

        Agency agency = agencyFind.findById(agencyId);
        assertEquals(agency.getId(), agencyId);
    }

    @Test
    @Transactional
    void find_agency_by_id_that_not_exist(){

        assertThrows(Exception.class, () -> agencyFind.findById(ContentGenerator.customIdLower()));
    }

    @Test
    @Transactional
    void find_agency_list(){

        List<Agency> agencyList = agencyFind.findAllCriteria(AgencyFindCriteriaMother.empty());
        assertTrue(agencyList.size() > 0);
    }

    @Test
    @Transactional
    void find_agency_list_using_criteria(){

        AgencyCreateDto agencyCreateDto = AgencyCreateDtoMother.random();
        Long agencyId = agencyCreate.create(agencyCreateDto).getResult().get("id");

        AgencyFindCriteria agencyFindCriteria = AgencyFindCriteriaMother.randomWithSpecificName(agencyCreateDto.getName());
        List<Agency> agencyList = agencyFind.findAllCriteria(agencyFindCriteria);

        assertTrue(agencyList.stream().anyMatch(agency -> agency.getId().equals(agencyId)));
    }

    @Test
    @Transactional
    void delete_agency(){

        Long agencyId = createAgency();
        assertDoesNotThrow(() -> agencyDelete.deleteById(agencyId));
    }

    @Test
    @Transactional
    void delete_agency_that_not_exist(){

        assertThrows(Exception.class, () -> agencyDelete.deleteById(ContentGenerator.customId()));
    }

}
```

If I launch the tests without @Transactional tags, all run well, but it dirty the database.
If I launch the test with @Transactional tags, some tests fails, for example, update_agency().
The error is:

```
Unexpected exception thrown: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: Unexpected exception thrown: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertionFailureBuilder.build(AssertionFailureBuilder.java:152)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertDoesNotThrow.createAssertionFailedError(AssertDoesNotThrow.java:84)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertDoesNotThrow.assertDoesNotThrow(AssertDoesNotThrow.java:53)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertDoesNotThrow.assertDoesNotThrow(AssertDoesNotThrow.java:36)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertDoesNotThrow(Assertions.java:3136)
    at app//agency.AgencyTest.update_agency(AgencyTest.java:72)
    at java.base@17.0.7/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base@17.0.7/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base@17.0.7/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base@17.0.7/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at app//org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:727)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:156)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:147)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:86)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:103)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:93)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.invoke(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:92)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.invoke(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:86)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$7(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:217)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:213)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:138)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:68)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:151)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base@17.0.7/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base@17.0.7/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:108)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:96)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:75)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.processAllTestClasses(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:99)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.access$000(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.stop(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:75)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.stop(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:61)
    at java.base@17.0.7/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base@17.0.7/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base@17.0.7/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base@17.0.7/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:94)
    at jdk.proxy1/jdk.proxy1.$Proxy2.stop(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker$3.run(TestWorker.java:193)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.executeAndMaintainThreadName(TestWorker.java:129)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.execute(TestWorker.java:100)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.execute(TestWorker.java:60)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.ActionExecutionWorker.execute(ActionExecutionWorker.java:56)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:133)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:71)
    at app//worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.run(GradleWorkerMain.java:69)
    at app//worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.main(GradleWorkerMain.java:74)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at java.base/java.util.ImmutableCollections.uoe(ImmutableCollections.java:142)
    at java.base/java.util.ImmutableCollections$AbstractImmutableCollection.clear(ImmutableCollections.java:149)
    at org.hibernate.type.CollectionType.replaceElements(CollectionType.java:525)
    at org.hibernate.type.CollectionType.replace(CollectionType.java:705)
    at org.hibernate.type.TypeHelper.replace(TypeHelper.java:117)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.copyValues(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:490)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.entityIsPersistent(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:211)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:184)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:81)
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:107)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireMerge(SessionImpl.java:830)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:816)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:307)
    at jdk.proxy3/jdk.proxy3.$Proxy143.merge(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save(SimpleJpaRepository.java:613)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker$RepositoryFragmentMethodInvoker.lambda$new$0(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:288)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:136)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:120)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:516)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:285)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:628)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:168)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:143)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:77)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:163)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:218)
    at jdk.proxy3/jdk.proxy3.$Proxy147.save(Unknown Source)
    at .agency.application.update.AgencyUpdate.update(AgencyUpdate.java:25)
    at agency.AgencyTest.lambda$update_agency$1(AgencyTest.java:72)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertDoesNotThrow.assertDoesNotThrow(AssertDoesNotThrow.java:49)
```

Why it fail?
Note that this agency object is saved in three relational tables with foraign keys.
Regards

**ADDED MORE INFORMATION**

AgencyUpdate class

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@Service
public class AgencyUpdate {

    @Autowired
    AgencyJpaRepository agencyJpaRepository;

    @Autowired
    AgencyFind agencyFind;

    public void update(Long agencyId, AgencyUpdateDto agencyUpdateDto){

        Agency agency = agencyFind.findById(agencyId);
        agency.aggregate(agencyUpdateDto);
        agencyJpaRepository.save(agency);
    }
}
```

Agency class

```
@Getter
@EqualsAndHashCode
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@DynamicUpdate
@Builder
public class Agency {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @Column(name = "technical_partner")
    private String technicalPartner;

    @Column(name = "connector_partner")
    private String connectorPartner;

    private String certification;

    @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @CollectionTable(name = "agency_support_contact", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name = "agency_id"))
    private List<SupportContact> supportContact;

    @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @CollectionTable(name = "agency_notification_email", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name = "agency_id"))
    private List<NotificationEmail> notificationEmail;

    public void aggregate(AgencyUpdateDto agencyUpdateDto){

        if (agencyUpdateDto.getName() != null)
            name = agencyUpdateDto.getName();

        if (agencyUpdateDto.getTechnicalPartner() != null)
            technicalPartner = agencyUpdateDto.getTechnicalPartner();

        if (agencyUpdateDto.getConnectorPartner() != null)
            connectorPartner = agencyUpdateDto.getConnectorPartner();

        if (agencyUpdateDto.getCertification() != null)
            certification = agencyUpdateDto.getCertification();

        if (agencyUpdateDto.getSupportContactList() != null)
            supportContact = agencyUpdateDto.getSupportContactList().stream().map(SupportContactFactory::create).toList();

        if (agencyUpdateDto.getNotificationEmailList() != null)
            notificationEmail = agencyUpdateDto.getNotificationEmailList().stream().map(NotificationEmailFactory::create).toList();

    }

}
```

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to use @Transactional on test methods, this is not what it's made for

Comment: @Ismail it is a very good idea to make the tests transactional as that will cleanup the dirt after the test method. Instead of repopulating the database for each test you can now run tests directly or even in parallel.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can put @Transactional on your class, not for every test
2. If you want keep your database is clean, you need add @Rollback on top your class's name
3. The error is caused by an immutable collection, since you did not attach the AgencyCreateDtoMother.random () implementation and the NotificationEmail, SupportContact classes, I can assume that when the random () method is called, an entity is created with some new parameter that is not in the hibernate context when updating, he tries to merge new ones changes, although this type should already be in the hibernate context, if you put an end to the thrown exception, it will be clear what the problem is

Comment: Hi @Jenia
1.- This is irrelevant, I prefer to have the Transactional in each test because it is more explicit. And not all tests will always be transactional.
2.- The Transactional tag by default already has Rollback = true.
3.- I don't think it's immutability's fault. If I do manual tests it works fine. If I remove the transactional it works fine too. Nevertheless I will try it.
Thanks for your time

Comment: Yes.. the error was caused by immutable collection. I've changed it and now the test are passed successfully. Thanks you!